# python turtle fill alternate squares

Tags: python, fill, subroutine, turtle-graphics

i have created a program that creates a 10x10 grid of squares (30x30):
I am trying to write a subroutine that fills every 2nd square (like a checkerboard).
here is what I have so far, but can't get it to work

```
def colour():
for j in range(5):
    for i in range (4):
        turtle.fillcolor('black')
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.forward(30)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.end_fill()
turtle.forward(60)
```

any help please

Comment: What is the problem that you are having?

Comment: it doesn't fill the alternate square

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is `begin_fill` and `end_fill` were in the nested loop, so it was trying to fill each line of the square and not the finished shape. I also added `turtle.pu() and turtle.pd()` to get rid of the dragging line.

```
turtle.fillcolor('black')
for j in range(5):
    turtle.begin_fill()
    for i in range (4):
        turtle.forward(30)
        turtle.right(90)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.forward(60)
    turtle.pd()
```

If you did want the unfilled squares to show between the filled ones, a few quick edits could fix that:

```
turtle.fillcolor('black')
for j in range(10):
    if j & 1:
        turtle.begin_fill()
    for i in range (4):
        turtle.forward(30)
        turtle.right(90)
    if j & 1:
        turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.forward(30)
```

Comment: Glad I could help, you may want to accept the answer and close the question.